# How can I encode an image sequence to a 24bit RGB888 AVI file on OSX?

Tags: macos, codec, avi

I would like to convert an image sequence(PNG or JPG) to an RGB888 avi file on OSX.

I used VirtualDub on Windows, but I'd rather not go back and forth between operating systems if I can. I did try running VirtualDub on OSX via Wine(command line/ Bottler and WhineSkin) with no luck.

Is there any simple solution for converting an image sequence to raw avi formats (24bit RGB888, 8bit Luminance (Y from YUV), etc.) ? Perhaps a codec for Quicktime/VLC/ffmpeg/etc ?

Comment: What format are your input images? Do you have a sample?

Comment: Oops, forgot to mentioned. PNG would be preferable, but JPG sequence would also work. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ffmpeg` does work, but for my purposes (passing the video to bespoke firmware) I also needed to tweak a few bytes in the header file for the encoded video to work.